# Error while saving product in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

All of a sudden i am getting this error in admin panel while saving a change in products.

> Warning:
>   include(/chroot/home/shireeni/shireeninc.com/html/osc/lib/Zend/Log.php):
>   failed to open stream: Too many open files  in
>   /chroot/home/shireeni/shireeninc.com/html/osc/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 94
>
> #0 ///html/osc/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2,
>   'include(/chroot...', '/chroot/home/sh...', 94, Array)  #1
>   /html/osc/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()  #2
>   [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Zend_Log')  #3
>   /html/osc/app/Mage.php(859): spl_autoload_call('Zend_Log')  #4
>   /html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(741):
>   Mage::logException(Object(Exception))  #5
>   /html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
>
> #6/html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')  #7
>   /html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>    #8 /html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()  #9
>   /html/osc/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)  #10
>   html/osc/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')  #11 {main}
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning:
>   include(  html/osc/lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Exception.php): failed to
>   open stream: Too many open files in
>   html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68' in
>   html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0
>   html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php(68):
>   mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(/chroot...', '/chroot/home/sh...',
>   68, Array) #1   html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php(68):
>   __autoload() #2 [internal function]: __autoload('Zend_Search_Luc...') #3   html/osc/lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/File/Filesystem.php(67): spl_autoload_call('Zend_Search_Luc...') #4
>   html/osc/lib/Zend/Search/Lucene/Storage/Directory/Filesystem.php(186):
>   Zend_Search_Lucene_Storage_File_Filesyste in
>   html/osc/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error threw me into various directions from checking the server logs to suggesting issue on the hosting side but just out of the blue stumbled upon [this](https://php4u.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213956706-PHP-Warning-failed-to-open-stream-Too-many-open-files-in-) link. Long story short just,**Reindex Data** from admin panel and this fixed the issue at once